# how to insert values into google sheets with merged rows

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a sheet with merged rows like such. When i enter values, I have to press enter repeatedly to get positioned to the next cell. Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to the next merged cell under me?

Comment: You have not shown any row numbers or column letters; so we don't know what is merged. Therefore, your question is not clear.

Comment: edited @ErikTyler

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just hit the down arrow on your keyboard to move down to the next merged cell underneath where you are.

[image]